# Why does cygwin's scp set the permssions to 000 when copying to Linux?

Tags: permissions, cygwin, scp

When I'm copying files from my Windows box to a Linux box using cygwin's `scp`, the permissions come out as `000`. This doesn't happen when I copy from Linux to Linux, so I'm thinking it's related to some configuration on my Windows box. But where is that configuration?

*Edit:* Under `bash`, `umask` prints `0022`. The behavior of `scp` is the same, whether I'm running `bash` or `CMD`.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some other pages discussing the issue. The first is about *scp*, while the second is about 000 permissions with another programs:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/124944/incorrect-permissions-after-copying-over-scp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828037/cygwin-sets-file-permission-to-000
- http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/vim-and-file-permissions-on-Windows-7-td61390.html

Apparently this is a problem with Cygwin's emulation of Unix-type file permissions on Windows filesystems with ACLs. The solution is to alter Cygwin's `/etc/fstab` file to make Cygwin ignore ACLs. Copying from one of those:

> cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.install
>
> echo "none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user,noacl 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
>
> To activate the new setting, logout and login again
>   logout ssh Adminstrator@hostname
>   Then stop and start your cygwin processes.

Comment: This worked for me.  Transfered files no longer have 000 mode.  Not sure why this doesn't have more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Run `umask` to see if the rights are being masked off.  The fewer the bits set, the more rights that should be set.  `umask 022` is a common setting (disabling writing by group and other).

Comment: within bash umask is 0022 (which is strange, being 4 digits).  Within the cmd prompt (where I am when I'm running scp, it doesn't exist so) it appears to be a builtin command.

Comment: The highest digit is for suid/sgid/sticky, which can be omitted when setting the mask, and, yes, umask is built into the shell.

Comment: Just came back to the question.  I'd love to accept an answer, and while umask does show some things, it's still not an answer to the question.  May just be that scp is broken.